# Xcode 12でアーカイブ エラー

Tags: xcode

Xcode 12 で アーカイブ エラー が出た場合どうしたらいいですか ？

> Failed to create provisioning profile.
> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

Answer (score 0):

私自身は Mac も iPhone も所持していませんが、エラーメッセージで検索すると例えば
以下のようなページがヒットします。

[Xcodeエラー解決！！](https://marimoko3.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/26/134621)

> Xcodeの入っているMacにiPhoneを接続したら直りました。